# checking if variable isset then encrypt user post not working

Tags: php, encryption, md5

```
<?php

$password = $_POST["password"];

if (isset($password) == true){
    echo "your password = ".$password."<hr>";
    echo "Encrypted password = ".md5($password)."<hr>";
}else{
    echo "please enter your password";
};

echo'
<form action="index.php" method="post" >
password : <input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" />
';

?>
```

in this code i want to encrypt user password using md5 function 
 but when the user enter nothing it echo

> d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

and used isset function to fix this but it is not working

Comment: Try `if (isset($password)){` instead of `if (isset($password) == true){`

Comment: As a note, you are NOT encrypting the password, but only hashing it. As another important note, MD5 hashes are NOT secure for passwords (especially without a salt!)

Comment: Very true @drmarvelous,

Comment: @drmarvelous I came here to say the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code worked

```
<?php

$password = $_POST["password"];

if ($password == ""){ 
    echo "please enter your password";
}else{
    echo "your password = ".$password."<hr>";
    echo "Encrypted password = ".md5($password)."<hr>";
};

echo'
<form action="index.php" method="post" >
password : <input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" />
';

?>
```

Comment: sometimes its not just about having a working script, I still advice to check your `$_POST` before addressing any expected variable of it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
// set the variable if it was given, otherwise emtpy
$password = array_key_exists('password', $_POST) ? $_POST['password'] : '';

// confirm this is not an empty string
if ($password != '') {
// ... the rest
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$password = $_POST["password"];

if (isset($password) == true){
    echo "your password = ".$password."<hr>";
    echo "Encrypted password = ".md5($password)."<hr>";
}else{
    echo "please enter your password";
};
```

to this

```
if (isset($_POST["password"]) == true){
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    echo "your password = ".$password."<hr>";
    echo "Encrypted password = ".md5($password)."<hr>";
}else{
    echo "please enter your password";
};
```

Because, when you first time load you page the `$_POST['password']` is not set. So it will face trouble to load you form.

Comment: how this will be executed if the variable is not defined ?
if (isset($_POST["password"]) == true)

Comment: Good point. Actually `isset($_POST["password"])` check wheter the variable is defined/set or not. You can also write like `if(isset($_POST["password"]))` to check whether the variable is set or not. If not set then it will just load your form. But if set, it will work to show the password.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `$_POST` as explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) is an associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST. So its good practice to check existence of any expected variables directly using the `$_POST` itself and **before** using them

e.g. `array_key_exists('password', $_POST);`, `isset($_POST['password']);`, etc.

In other word the condition in your script can be changed to:

```
if (array_key_exists('password', $_POST)){
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    echo "your password = ".$password."<hr>";
    echo "Encrypted password = ".md5($password)."<hr>";
}else{
    echo "please enter your password";
};
```

Comment: "hashed" password, not encrypted.

Comment: @drmarvelous, I approved your point first time, in my answer her i'm just answering the question ;)